# Failed to unlink socket file: Operation not permitted

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I am facing this issue where I am unable to get my `mongod` started successfully:

This is the error:

> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.922+05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire
> specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.922+05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling
> TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols
> 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.924+05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP
> FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set
> tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.925+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.925+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.925+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.925+05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading
> initialized"} {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.925+05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB
> starting","attr":{"pid":24280,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"ehsan-HP"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.925+05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build
> Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.3","gitVersion":"f803681c3ae19817d31958965850193de067c516","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL
> 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.925+05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating
> System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.925+05:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set
> by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.926+05:00"},"s":"E",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to
> unlink socket
> file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not
> permitted"}} {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.926+05:00"},"s":"F",
> "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal
> assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1125}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-01-13T12:33:59.926+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",
> "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after
> fassert() failure\n\n"}

What I have tried so far:

Delete `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` file and then start `mongod` by doing `sudo service mongod start`. It didn't work. The file `mongodb-27017.sock` created after running this comand has the following permissions:

```
srwx------ 1 mongodb mongodb 0 January 13 12:49 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

These are the permissions of `/data/db`:

```
$ ls -la /data/db
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4096 January 13 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4096 January 13 11:35 ..
```

What is going wrong here? This is my `mongod` version:

```
$ mongod --version
db version v6.0.3
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.3",
    "gitVersion": "f803681c3ae19817d31958965850193de067c516",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu1804",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

I am on `Ubuntu 18`.

EDIT:
Here are the contents of `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Jan 13 13:40:24 ehsan-HP sudo:    ehsan : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/home/ehsan ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service mongod restart
Jan 13 13:40:24 ehsan-HP sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 13 13:40:24 ehsan-HP sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: The code that lead to that error appears to be just attempting to delete that socket: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r6.0.3/src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp#L1118-L1125.  Perhaps the operating system logs will provide some clues.

Comment: @Joe which logs exactly should I check?

Comment: Depends on your OS.  A few possibilities are messages, system.log, auth.log

Comment: @Joe I have updated the question with the said logs details.